# Installing DescTools in 3.3.3 causes RStudio to crash

Tags: r, statistics, spss, cran, desctools

I'm using R 3.3.3, because it can be read by SPSS 25. If I try to instal the package "DescTools" the app closes itself.  CRAN says that "DescTools" works on R 3.3.0 and above.  Are there different packages? If so, how do I replace the faulty one, with one that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear a dependent package of DescTools is not available and so I can't reproduce the error:

```
> install.packages("mvtnorm")
Warning in install.packages :
package 'mvtnorm' is not available (for R version 3.3.3)
```

Try to update to the current version.

Comment: I can't update to the current version, because SPSS doesn't work with the current version.

Comment: Same problem for R 3.4.4 since dependent package `mvtnorm` published on 2019-03-05 is known to work on R 3.5.0 or higher. See mvtnorm package description on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for R 3.4.4 since dependent package `mvtnorm` published on 2019-03-05 is known to work on R 3.5.0 or higher. [mvtnorm package description on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html)